# Parsing error: the type cast expression is expected to be wrapped in parentheses

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tried to create an object inside the "tracks" array under "You Give Love a Bad Name"

```
export default class Cart extends React.Component {
    render() {
      var collection = {
        "2548": {
          "album": "Slippery When Wet",
          "artist": "Bon Jovi",
          "tracks": [
            "Let It Rock", **
            "You Give Love a Bad Name": {
              "love": "bad",
              "you": "George"
            } **
          ]
        }
      };
      return ();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does ** denote?  What's the actual output that you expecy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you exactly want.

because this format looks not good.

```
var collection = {
        "2548": {
          "album": "Slippery When Wet",
          "artist": "Bon Jovi",
          "tracks": [
            "Let It Rock",
            {
              "You Give Love a Bad Name": {
                "love": "bad",
                "you": "George"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      };
```

Comment: it worked, but now I'm getting 'love is not defined'

Comment: @MichaelOrr if you mention what you try and want, you can get the answer easily.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by this? Are you saying I should post another question? I'm going to accept your answer, don't worry.

Comment: You said you got `love is not defined`, but I don't know how did you get that. let me know what did you do or your code.

Comment: I just added the curly braces, as per your example, but then it went inside the "You Give Love a Bad Name" object, and I got a new error ("love" is not defined, no undef)

Comment: it's okay, I'll just post another question in 90 minutes if I can't figure it out.